I want to buy a 5.1 sound system from India (priced at 18,000 rupees) and bring it to Bangladesh. What would be the procedure?
I am planning to buy a 5.1 home theater soundbar from Zebronics. How can I pay the tax and VAT to legally bring the product into Bangladesh? Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.

Will you travel with it or will you buy it from home?

What has your own research on the topic revealed?

Typically you declare it at customs when you cross the border. Present a receipt for the goods and the custom officer will calculate and take your payment.  If you want to ship it, you will need to provide customs paperwork to the shipper who will collect tax and duty up front.
